# Pubsub doesn't return logs when accessed with new subscription

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I am a newbie to GCP.

We are sending logs to a Pubsub topic, and created a pull subscription for that topic.  When I used the glcoud command and read from that subscription it returned logs as expected.  (someone else created the topic and the first subscription.  I am the owner of the project however.)
Then I created  a new pull subscription for the same topic (on Pubsub UI I can see both subscriptions.) When I use the glcoud command to read from the new subscription, it returns 0 items.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Cloud Pub/Sub, a subscription will only get messages published *after* the subscription was created. If you publish more messages, you should receive them in a subsequent pull request.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.   That's too bad since often one may want to back populate some table based on the logs already in the queue.  As an example, Kafka offers an option to the consumer to start consuming from the earliest point or the latest in the queue.  Seems that Pubsub only allows for the latter.